# 403 Forbidden on OS X with symbolic link

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-mountain-lion, symbolic-link

I just upgraded to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion to find that my web server setup was ruined by the upgrade. I managed to get PHP and Apache back up and running, but I still do not have my old setup from Lion up and running. For my old setup, I used a shady technique in order to make Apache work with Dropbox; in `/Users/Andy/Sites/project1`, I had a symbolic link, which pointed to `/Users/Andy/Dropbox/MyFolder/dev/project1`. I found that I could not direct my virtual host to Dropbox directly (probably something with permissions that didn't work). However, it worked perfectly with a symbolic link. So in this way, I could store my projects in Dropbox and use my local Apache server.

After setting Apache up to work with my `Sites` folder, I can now point my virtual hosts to sub folders in this directory and this works fine. However, when I try to point it to my symbolic link, I get a 403 Forbidden error. I really want to use Dropbox for my small projects where SVN or Git is overkill. Here is part of my configuration:

**/etc/hosts:**

`127.0.0.1  test.dev`

**/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.dev
DocumentRoot "/Users/Andy/Sites/project1"

<Directory "/Users/Andy/Sites/project1">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**My symbolic link:**

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 Andy  staff     59 Sep 30 12:01 project1 -> /Users/Andy/Dropbox/Myfolder/dev/project1/
```

**/etc/apache2/users/Andy.conf** (this seems to work fine since I can serve files from the `Sites` folder):

```
<Directory "/Users/Andy/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also get the same error if I don't use my virtual host, i.e. `localhost/~Andy/project1`.

Perhaps there is a better setup that does not involve symbolic links and still allows me to use Dropbox, and then I am very interested to know. Otherwise, does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I guess it's all about permissions, so which permissions should my `~/Dropbox/MyFolder/dev/project1` folder have? I am no good at permissions, but I tried to use `chmod a+rw project1` without any luck.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by pointing my directory in `/etc/apache2/users/Andy.conf` to `/Users/Andy/Dropbox/MyFolder/dev` like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/Andy/Dropbox/My own folder/dev">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I updated my virtual host to point to my project's folder like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.dev
DocumentRoot "/Users/Andy/Dropbox/MyFolder/dev/project1"

<Directory "/Users/Andy/Dropbox/MyFolder/dev/project1">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I could have sworn that I couldn't get this to work on OS X Lion, but perhaps I took a slightly different approach back then. Nevertheless, it works for me now on OS X Mountain Lion.